# Inline `cfg_attr(feature = x, path = "file.rs")` doesn't work

Tags: rust

According to the [documentation for cfg_attr](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg_attr-attribute), it is possible to do both of these:

```
#[cfg_attr(windows, path = "windows.rs")]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "magic", sparkles, crackles)]
```

However, I'm seeing an error when trying to use them together.

```
// this works
#[cfg(connection = "websocket")]
#[path = "websocket.rs"]
mod protocol;

// file not found for module `protocol`
#[cfg_attr(connection = "websocket", path = "websocket.rs")]
mod protocol ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cfg` enables a whole item conditionally. `cfg_attr` enables one or more *attributes* conditionally.

In this:

```
#[cfg(connection = "websocket")]
#[path = "websocket.rs"]
mod protocol;
```

the whole `protocol` module will only be included if the condition is true, but in this:

```
#[cfg_attr(connection = "websocket", path = "websocket.rs")]
mod protocol;
```

the `protocol` module is always enabled. If the condition is true, the compiler will look for its source in `websocket.rs`, but if it's false, it will look in `protocol.rs`. In other words, it's equivalent to:

```
#[cfg(connection = "websocket")]
#[path = "websocket.rs"]
mod protocol;

#[cfg(not(connection = "websocket"))]
mod protocol;
```